# iOS Pointer Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, pointers

I seem to have a pointer problem and I can't seem o fix it. Could someone help me, please?

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Finished Downloading Image: %@" ,[connection.originalRequest.URL absoluteString]);
    UIImage *CompiledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:ImageData];
    SEL selector=@selector(ImageDownloadingCompleted:Image:);
    if([[self Delegate] respondsToSelector:selector]){
        [[self Delegate] ImageDownloadingCompleted:self Image:CompiledImage];
    }
    else{
        if(Target){
            *Target=CompiledImage;
        }
    }
    // NSLog(@"Image Size:%i", [ImageData length]);
}
```

`Target` is a private variable of type `UIImage` (declared: `UIImage *Target;`) 
`CompiledImage` is a `UIImage` as well. What I want to do is set the contents of the address of target to be the Contents of CompiledTarget. This results in the following error:

> Assigning to 'UIImage' from incompatible type 'UIImage *__strong'

I tried :

```
memccpy(__bridge Target, &CompiledImage, sizeof(Target),sizeof(Target));
```

and I get this error:

> Expected expression

Comment: Just a piece of suggestion. Use http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ instead of NSURLConnection. This made my life easy ;)

Comment: @ACB I already did myfriend :) thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to just set it as,

```
Target = CompiledImage;
```

No need of `*`. Since both are pointers basically you are assigning the memory address and not copying the contents if you use the above code.

On a side note, please start variable names with lowercase letters. `Target` normally represents a class name. As per apple coding conventions, it should be `target`.

As per your comment, you can do the following,

In ViewController class, declare a `UIImage` as `@property`,

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *downloadedImage;
```

While doing URL call,

```
NSImageLoader *imageLoader = [[NSImageLoader alloc] init];
[imageLoader setTarget:self];//setting current viewController as target instead of UIImage
```

When image is downloaded,

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Finished Downloading Image: %@" ,[connection.originalRequest.URL absoluteString]);
    UIImage *CompiledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:ImageData];
    SEL selector=@selector(ImageDownloadingCompleted:Image:);
    if([[self Delegate] respondsToSelector:selector]){
        [[self Delegate] ImageDownloadingCompleted:self Image:CompiledImage];
    }
    else{
        if(Target){
            Target.downloadedImage = CompiledImage;//or [Target setDownloadedImage:CompiledImage];
        }
    }
    // NSLog(@"Image Size:%i", [ImageData length]);
}
```

In your ViewController class, now you can access image as, `self.downloadedImage` which will have same as in `CompiledImage` with same memory address pointing to the same location.

An alternative way is to declare `UIImage *Target` as `UIImage **Target` in your `NSImageLoader` class. And while calling `setTarget` method, use `[imageLoader setTarget:&Target];`. Inside this method you need to set target as `Target = Target;`

**Update:**
Based on your comments it should be like this,

```
for( NSDictionary *CurrentActivity in [Profile UserActivities]) {
        ...
        UIImage *WineImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.gif"];
        NSImageLoader *loader=[[NSImageLoader alloc] initWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[TempSettings URL],[CurrentActivity objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]]];
        [loader setTarget:&WineImage];
        [loader startDownloading];
        [self addSubview:Activity];
        Counter++;
    }
```

Then in NSImageLoader.h file @interface,

```
 __strong UIImage **Target; //This should be strong not autoreleasing
```

In NSImageLoader.m file,

```
- (void)setTarget:(UIImage *__strong *)iTarget{ //change here also
     Target = target; 
} 


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Finished Downloading Image: %@" ,[connection.originalRequest.URL absoluteString]);
    UIImage *CompiledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:ImageData];
    SEL selector=@selector(ImageDownloadingCompleted:Image:);
    if([[self Delegate] respondsToSelector:selector]){
        [[self Delegate] ImageDownloadingCompleted:self Image:CompiledImage];
    }
    else{
        if(Target){
            *Target = CompiledImage;
        }
    }
    // NSLog(@"Image Size:%i", [ImageData length]);
}
```

**Update2:**

Using the approach of passing UIImageView, you can do the following,

```
    for( NSDictionary *CurrentActivity in [Profile UserActivities]) {
        ...
        UIImage *WineImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.gif"];
        NSImageLoader *loader=[[NSImageLoader alloc] initWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[TempSettings URL],[CurrentActivity objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]]];
        [loader setTarget:Activity];//pass imageview and let the delegate method set image
        [loader startDownloading];
        [self addSubview:Activity];
        Counter++;
    }

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Finished Downloading Image: %@" ,[connection.originalRequest.URL absoluteString]);
    UIImage *CompiledImage=[UIImage imageWithData:ImageData];
    SEL selector=@selector(ImageDownloadingCompleted:Image:);
    if([[self Delegate] respondsToSelector:selector]){
        [[self Delegate] ImageDownloadingCompleted:self Image:CompiledImage];
    }
    else{
        if(Target){
            Target.image = CompiledImage;
        }
    }
    // NSLog(@"Image Size:%i", [ImageData length]);
}
```

Here pass imageview and let the delegate method set image in that once you have downloaded the image.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however, it wouldn't work as this would assign the memory address of compiledimage to Target, what I want to do is the exact opposite. Target is a pointer to an object in the view controller, and this function is executed inside a class. I want to change the image in the view controller by using the Target pointer. This is why I want to copy the data to that particular memory address.

Comment: @user1889357, That is slightly confusing. How are you passing the reference to that viewcontroller to this class? Certainly the above code which you used wont work. Can you please add the declaration of Target in and how this class is called from the viewcontroller class. There should be an easier way.

Comment: Ok, so I have a class named NSImageLoader.. in the class I have a function:

-(void) setTarget:(id)target{
    Target=target;
}

in my private variables for the class I have: id Target;

now in the viewcontroller, I created a UIImage variable and passed it to setTarget. what I want is when the Image is downloaded in connectionDidFinishLoading is to set the image of the view controller (which i have passed as a target in setTarget to point to the new image that has just been loaded.

Comment: @Abedjoud, In that case why dont you set your viewcontroller as the target. For eg:- when you are calling setTarget method, pass viewcontroller itself as the target and not UIImage. After that in this delegate method once you get the image, set it as `target.image = CompiledImage;` That is the way to do this. That will automatically assign the same memory address of UIImage as CompiledImage to viewController.UIImageObject which you have defined in that class.

Comment: @Abedjoud, An alternative way is to pass Target as `&Target` and then while setting use the above code of yours as `*Target = CompiledImage;`. for eg:- when you are calling setTarget method, do it as `setTarget:&Target`. And then rest of the code above in your question will also work.

Comment: @ACB the problem  with sending the view controller is that the UIImages are being created in a loop dynamically, there is no explicit iVar in the View Controller to reference it with. as For the setTarget &target... it's giving an error, since i'm saving it in a local variable Target... what type should Target be if i was to save &target to it? currently it's UIImage*

Comment: @Abedjoud, Your local variable Target should be declared as `UIImage **Target;`

Comment: @Abedjoud, Wait. If you dont have any iVar in view controller, where are you planning to save this image datas? What is Target passed in setTarget method in calling class?

Comment: Target in setTarget is passed a UIImage which is dynamically created and added to the subview: 

for( NSDictionary *CurrentActivity in [Profile UserActivities]){
        ...
        
        UIImage *WineImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.gif"];
        NSImageLoader *loader=[[NSImageLoader alloc] initWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[TempSettings URL],[CurrentActivity objectForKey:@"ImageURL"]]];
        [loader setTarget:WineImage];
        [loader startDownloading];
        [self addSubview:Activity];
        Counter++;
    }

Comment: @Abedjoud, Are you calling `[loader setTarget:&WineImage]`? Is there `&` before that?

Comment: the class gives off an error when i try to declare a UIIMage **Target;
Error: /Users/abedjoud/Desktop/My Projects/iOS/CalARG/FiveCorkz/FiveCorkz/FiveCorkz/NSImageLoader.m:32:10: Assigning 'UIImage *__autoreleasing *' to 'UIImage *__strong *' changes retain/release properties of pointer

Comment: UIImage **Target; //Throws off:   Pointer to non-const type "UIImage *" with no explicit ownership
-(void) setTarget:(UIImage **)target{
   Target=target; //throws: Assigning 'UIImage *__autoreleasing *' to 'UIImage *__strong *' changes retain/release properties of pointer
}

[IMageLoader setTarget:&image]; //Throws: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'UIImage *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: @Abedjoud, Can you tell me if activity is an ImageView which has this image and is created inside that for loop as local variable? In that case there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: I know i could send the ActivityView into the ImageLoader and just call [ActivityView setImage:NewImage];
but if i use this, i will affect the reusability of the Class NSImageLoader as I will have to send an ActivityView to use it, instead of it jut writing to an ImageClass

Comment: @ACB So what you're saying is what i'm trying to do is unsafe right? but if so, then why do we have the ** to get the pointer of a pointer and change that?

Comment: @Abedjoud, Can you please check with my update section again. Not the update 2. I have removed @property part and added it in `@interface`.

Comment: @ACB ok i fixed the UIImage **Target by changing it to: __strong UIImage **Target; now it works, the code compiles and all, but it fails when it tries to assign *Target=*target in setTarget

Comment: @Abedjoud, Try it as `Target = target;` What is the error it is showing? If not working check `**Target = **Target;`

Comment: @ACB I changed the UIImage **Target from __strong to __autoreleasing and that solved the problem. Now the other thing I have noticed (which is going to render my idea completely useless) is the fact the UIImageView makes a copy of the image rather than retain it! so if you setImage and then you change that particular image, it won't change in the UIImageVIew

Comment: @Abedjoud, That is what I was thinking. You should ideally pass `UIImageView` in this. I have never heard of anyone passing image like this. And you cant expect UIImageView to render the image if you just change the pointer to point to this new image. You have to call [activity setImage:image] to render the image.

Comment: Am I wrong about the fact that it copies rather than retains?

Comment: @Abedjoud, It may not be a copy. It might be switching the pointers. But if you have to see the new image in view, you have to call setImage of imageView which you are not doing in this way. So how will the imageView know that it has to render the new image in view. You should use my answer with UIImageView I guess.

Comment: do you think there is a way to change the UIImageView image without calling setImage?

Comment: @Abedjoud, I just now tried the approach you suggested. It works only if it is in the same class. If it is assigned from different class, the original value is lost when you are going back. So it is not due to the copy. The problem is when you are going back it is not retaining this pointer to new UIImage downloaded. It refers to the earlier one itself. But If I do this thing in same class, it works fine.

Comment: @Abedjoud, Got one issue with this code. I will update my answer. Please check with that and let me know if it works. Check the update section once again. Since you were using autoreleasing, it was getting released. Use strong instead.

Comment: @Abedjoud, Checked the whole thing using a sample project. You can get an image using my above code. But if you want to see that in imageView, you have to call `[imageview setImage:target];` Even setNeedsDisplay wont help. If you just call this, it automatically sets the new image which is stored in the pointer after downloading. So you can either use Update or Update 2. But with update, you have to call `[activity setImage:WineImage]` again after new image is downloaded. Another way to do this is by storing all imageViews or images in an array and then set the images once downloaded.

Comment: I am going to mark this answer as accepted as it sheds a lot of light on pointers. To preserve reusability, I ended up just creating another class that takes a type and UIActivityView and used NSImageLoader to download the image, and then used setImage..

Comment: @Abedjoud, Thanks.That is the approach I mentioned as using UIImageView. For table view lazy loading this is how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Make Target is pTarget? a pointer to a pointer then it makes sense
`*pTarget = compiledImage`
(as it is done with NSErrors often .. e.g. in core data)

you cant just memcpy the stuff since target has not the correct size allocated on the heap.

---

you cant Copy the real UIImage bytes in the memory because that isnt known to you and an implementation detail. you dont even know how big it is!

BUT you can copy the pointer to the image -- its memory address

---

```
UIImage *pointer1 = [UIImage imageWithFoo];
UUImage *pointer2 = pointer1;
```

now you can also declare an empty pointer and fill it later

```
UIImage *target = nil;
UIImage *pointer1 = [UIImage imageWithFoo];
target = pointer1;
```

so far so good but what if you want to PASS target to a function and THAT should fill it?

```
target = [self calculateImage];
```

but now you have it in asynchronous function

```
[self asyncCalculateImage:&target]; // you pass it a POINTER to the POINTER to fill :)
...
- (void)asyncCalculateImage:(UIImage**)pTarget {
    UIImage *pointer1 = [UIImage imageWithFoo];
    *pTarget = pointer1; //DEREFERENCE and fill pTarget
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Daij-Djan you're almost spot on in what I need! the problem is, i need to save the Target in a local variable using setTarget. and then when the connectiondelegate gets called, i need to do the dereferencing.. i tried:
 UIImage **pImage=&Target;
            *pImage=CompiledImage;
but i get this error:/Users/abedjoud/Desktop/My Projects/iOS/CalARG/FiveCorkz/FiveCorkz/FiveCorkz/NSImageLoader.m:84:22: Pointer to non-const type 'UIImage *' with no explicit ownership

Comment: ignore it and cast it to (UIImage*) -- arc complains about a const missing

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put * again, here CompiledImage itself is a pointer.

Simply use `Target=CompiledImage;`

Comment: Because this wont change the contents of the memory pointed to by Target, it will rather assign a new address to Target. I need to change the contents of the Target address not assign address a new pointer